# Where to put controller UserMailer.signup_confirmation(@user).deliver from Railscast on Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller, actionmailer

I'm following the railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email-revised which states that I should add

```
UserMailer.signup_confirmation(@user).deliver
```

to

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user, notice: "Signed up successfully."
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

after the line `if @user.save` ... But what if I am using devise? Do I need to add `UserMailer.signup_confirmation(@user).deliver`
 to another place where the Devise gem is hiding the equivalent of a users_controller  ?

Comment: made slight modification - typo before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Without Devise

Since, you are following the RailsCasts episode for `Sending Email` then in that case all you need to do is update `UsersController#create` as below:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    UserMailer.signup_confirmation(@user).deliver  ## Add this
    redirect_to @user, notice: "Signed up successfully."
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

### With Devise

**Option #1 Sending a welcome confirmation mail**

What you can do here is, override the `after_sign_in_path_for` method in ApplicationController as below:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ## ...
  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    UserMailer.signup_confirmation(@user).deliver  ## Add this
    your_path(resource)  ## Replace your_path with the path name where you want to send the user after sign in 
  end
end
```

**Option #2 Sending a welcome confirmation mail with confirmation token**

For this you will need to use Devise built-in `Confirmable` module.

> Confirmable: sends emails with confirmation instructions and verifies
>   whether an account is already confirmed during sign in.

Refer to **[Confirmable Documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable)**